# GPU and CPU volumetric render noise discrepancy

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

Below are a couple of images comparing quite a big discrepancy between GPU and CPU volumetric noise.
Same settings, much more noise on the GPU render!

Has anyone else experienced this?

The GPU must have a harder time clearing the noise for some reason at same Sample size..

[image: GPU render]

[image: CPU render]

The [original images are on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yJ5jDxrheBcnFvWnZaX0VSVHc/view?pref=2&pli=1).

Comment: I had the same problem. Without using any denoising, and while using volumetrics, CPU rendering resulted in less noise in lower samples. Without using volumetrics the difference disappeared. CPU-i5-9400f
GPU-r9 380

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some differences between CPU and GPU rendered images. Some have been fixed in 2.78, some have not. Maybe later. You can do nothing about this. 
Only one recommendation: use what works better in your case and don't combine CPU and GPU rendering for animation. :-)

[Blender 2.78 bugs fixes](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78/Bug_Fixes)